# Aligning Particles in a direction

Tags: particles, hair, force-fields

I want to arrange ellipsoid-shaped particles shown in the picture filled inside a sphere.

In the same way aligned from one pole to other (bipolar)

How can we do this using particle system ? How to align like this ?

[image]

[blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Ddw7Tsf62iwJw0y13yx2krj9CeZ1k2B/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Add a particle system to a UV Sphere object set to emitter. Make sure the number of faces in each direction of your sphere matches the desired amount of ellipsoid loops you want in the final setup.

[image]

Under *Source* set to *Faces*, turn off *Random Order* and *Even Distribution* and set Particles per Face to $1$.

[image]

Under the *Render* panel pick your ellipsoid and turn on *Object Rotation*.

Manually adjust the rotation of the original ellipsoid object to match your desired rotation.

If you want a "volumetric" setup with several layers of ellipsoids inside the volume, onion skin your UV Sphere with several concentric layers by duplicating and scaling down the mesh.

Comment: I know this comment will get deleted but this is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot man. God bless u.

Comment: Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).